# Form Issue - need to have two different Posts on the same FORM. - I am a complete Novice learning as I go

Tags: html

I have created a form which I need to email back to me and also send to Paypal for processing.

The FORM Header to email is - 
`<form name="paypal" action="formtoemail.php" method="post">`

and the FORM Header to send is - 
`<form name="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/ca/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">`
How can I combine these two different POSTs into the same form to be activated hopefully by one button?

Thank you in advance
Mike

Answer (score 2):

You can either use javascript to process the form and the submit it to the two different locations or you can use PHP server side to process the one form and then submit it to paypal.

***EDIT***

Here is an example of how to do it with Jquery which can also allow you to do validation before sending to either place.

**html**

```
<form id="myForm" action="someurl.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="username">
  <input type="submit" value="Post">
</form>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(function(){
  $('#myForm').submit(function(e){
    // Send to paypal
    $.post('https://www.paypal.com/ca/cgi-bin/webscr', $("#myForm").serialize());
    // Send to php script named in action of form tag
    $('#myForm').submit();
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks but my problem is I do not know how to do this. If you could point me to some sample code I can dissect it and try.

Comment: @Mike - I added an example using Jquery

Answer (score 0):

You can first post it to an Iframe (hidden or not), and capture the onload event of the Iframe to post the form to the destination you want the user to see.